# IQueryable with Entity Framework - order, where, skip and take have no effect

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, iqueryable

I'm using Entity Framework (code first) like this:

```
IQueryable<StammdatenEntityModel> query = dbSet;

query.OrderByDescending(s => s.CreateDateTime);

query.Where(s => s.Deleted == false);

if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(keyword))
{
    query.Where(s => s.SerialNumber.Contains(keyword)); //simplified for SO
}

query.Skip(skip);
query.Take(take);
```

However the `OrderByDescending`, `Where`, `Skip` and `Take` don't have any effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not using the result of query

```
IQueryable<StammdatenEntityModel> query = dbSet;
query = query.OrderByDescending(s => s.CreateDateTime);
query = query.Where(s => s.Deleted == false);
if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(keyword))
{
    query = query.Where(s => s.SerialNumber.Contains(keyword)); //simplified for SO
}
query = query.Skip(skip);
query = query.Take(take);
```